# Report viewer shows blank report

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2012, reportviewer

I have never used reports before and my knowledge is really limited. I have developed an application using C# and SQL Server 2012 Express and one of the features is to show customers account in ReportViewer.

This report gets its data from a stored procedure and for now everything works fine, but the client wants it to work on the desktop of several different machines.

So I made one machine work as a server with the others connecting to it by router and everything in the application works fine except the ReportViewer shows only a blank white report (but only on the client machines -- not the server)

I also tried updating the dataset's connection string in `app.config`.

What should I try next?

Comment: Are you trying to create a RDLC report in SQL Server?

Comment: @jdweng i dont understand you exactly but i created RDLC report in visual studio using report wizard and it's take data from dataset and the dataset has a stored procedure.

Comment: A RDLC is a text file in html format which you can open in notepad.  The query to the database is in the <COMANDTEXT> tag and is a query to the database,  Not sure what you mean by a dataset (c# dataset).  The response from the query is flat and fits into one table.  So you results may be in ds.Table[0].

Comment: @jdweng yes exactly , i'm only use first table (ds.Table[0]) , i used dataset because report wizard forced me to create one maybe there is another way i dont know

Comment: in server machine report viewer work fine with this connectionString(Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Dest;Integrated Security=True)  , but in client machine i edit connectionString like this(Data Source=192.168.0.107\SQLEXPRESS,49170;Initial Catalog=Dest;User ID=said;Password=said) every thing work except report viewer

Comment: The connection string in client should be exactly the same as in server except replace the localhost with the name or IP of the server.Integrated Security indicates you are using a Windows Credential.So for window credential to work the client PC and server PC needs to be in the same Group so windows can use a secure connection. Then the user need to have an account on both client and server PC.  So normally a group account is created on Server which has read/write access to the SQL Server.Normally in a large company you are using GROUP POLICY (talk to MIS).Then client PC have same user group.